# "Ability" vs. "faculty"

Tags: word-choice, differences, nouns

Looking up dictionaries I don't see a easy rule when to use *ability* vs. *faculty* in sense of a describing attribute . For example, "cognitive faculty" or "faculty of speech" seem to be standard terms, but then "learning or mental ability" seems more common than "learning faculty". The only pattern I see is that abilities are kind of innate(?).

Comment: It's not a distinction of meaning as such - just that certain combinations are more idiomatically established. The net result being that the more academic/clinical *faculty* tends to refer "innate, raw" potential (which you always had, and which can't be improved). Whereas *ability*, often refers to *current skill level* - which can improve or deteriorate. Depending on whether you practice, or allow skills to atrophy through disuse, for example.

Comment: Quick answer: 'faculty' is kind of general, referring to the ability in a species the possibility of X. 'Ability' means you can do X now. Also, 'faculty' has many very specific connotations (like with the individuals who teach at an institution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, and I don't think there's a Chicago or AP reference on this so YMMV:

- Ability - what degree of capability exists
- Faculty - is any capability present whatsoever

So, an infant has no *faculty* of speech, and a toddler has *faculty* but limited *ability*.